# How to create modal popup in Leafletjs?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

We can create default bindPopup content in LeafletJS using:

```
var popupContent = '<table class="table table-bordered">'
layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
```

How to create such a popup using modal, so that I can "beautify" with bootstrap, and add content such as modal header.

Comment: I think you may find https://github.com/mapshakers/leaflet-control-window helpful

Comment: It doesn't work when I use simultaneously both mapshakers/leaflet-control-window and bootstrap :(